# How to filter vector features randomly

Tags: vector, filter, openlayers, layer

Is it possible to create a random strategy filter? For instance, filtering out one vector from every three features?

If that isn't possible, is there any way to access the vector layer to filter out random features BEFORE it is rendered?

I've been looking for hours trying to figure this out. I would really appreciate some help with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A random strategy filter:

```
   var myRandomFilter = new OpenLayers.Filter({

            evaluate: function(context) {

                    return Math.random() < 0.3333;
            }
    });
```

Not so random::

```
   var myRandomFilter = new OpenLayers.Filter({

            count: 0,

            evaluate: function(context) {

                    return this.count++ % 3 == 0;

            }
    });
```

Usage in Layer.Vector:

```
strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed(),
    new OpenLayers.Strategy.Filter({filter: myRandomFilter})],
```